# USB portion of KVM Switch doesn't work when switching back to Windows PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, kvm-switch

I have a simple KVM switch connected to a Windows 10 PC and a Debian Linux PC - it connects a 3.5MM Audio jack, Displayport connection and 4 USB 2.0 connections. My keyboard and mouse are connected to two of the USB connections.

If I boot up the Windows PC, everything works as expected. If I switch to the Linux PC, everything works as expected. However if I switch to the Windows 10 PC either after booting it or after switching from it to the Linux PC, it stops detecting or even providing power to the USB ports.

I've opened up the switch and double checked all the solders and components on the USB hub and found no issues. I also found no issues switching between two Linux workstations. Upon experiencing the symptoms I also tried unplugging the KB and Mouse from the KVM switch and directly into different hubs on the Windows PC and it continued to not detect or provide power to them, so I'm lead to believe this is an issue with either Windows' USB device detection or the USB hardware on my Windows 10 PC.

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting from here - what should I do next? Has anyone else experienced this particular issue?

Comment: Make and model of the KVM?

Comment: “If I boot up the Windows PC, everything works as expected. If I switch to the Linux PC, everything works as expected. However if I switch to the Windows 10 PC either after booting it or after ...” - What?  Your description of the problem is confusing.  How can the Windows device both work and not work after you reboot it?

Comment: @Ramhound The Windows device only works if the KB/M are connected to it during boot and remain connected. If it is booted without them connected, or they are switched away and back, they no longer work.

Comment: I heard that switching usb you may get a message about  hardware removed 'cos it's like plugging and unplugging.. Maybe if you got one that supported Ps2 you may be ok though they are old.. funnily enough ps2 isn't "hot swappable", so plugging/unplugging might not work, but maybe a kvm supporting ps2 would keep the power on for them or something. Been ages since  I used them..And then there were the 5V stand by voltage on power supply that can change things.. i'm sure that's irrelevant to a kvm that is usb and doesn't support ps2.. and probably only ancient ones would support ps2 anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact issue you've described.  looks like the issue was the peripherals i was using was usb 2.0 - but the KVM switch used 3.0 ports, and so windows was not able to "find them" again when switching back.